# Trying to Insert Bulk record into the database at once using C# and MS SQL User-Defined Table type

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, dapper

I have written below C# code and SQL code; I got scenario to insert multiple records in database at once, so I tried below method, but it is not working from my MVC C# but when I fire query manually from SQL server then it works. I have given below code with dummy records.

```
try
{
       var dataTable = new DataTable();
       dataTable.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
       dataTable.Columns.Add("City", typeof(string));
       dataTable.Columns.Add("Age", typeof(string));

       dataTable.Rows.Add("ABC", "Mumbai", "24");
       dataTable.Rows.Add("DEF", "Nasik", "30");
       dataTable.Rows.Add("GHI", "Ahmedabad", "26");

       var ItemValues = dataTable.AsTableValuedParameter("dbo.typList");

       using(var con = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString()))
       {
           var output = con.Query<bool>("Usp_BulkInsert", ItemValues, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure, commandTimeout: 1000).SingleOrDefault();
       }
}
```

below is my SQL Stored Procedure and User-Defined Table type.

Stored Procedure:

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[Usp_BulkInsert] @ItemValues typList READONLY
--- Here i am assign User_Define_Table_Type to Variable and making it readonly
AS BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        BEGIN TRANSACTION;
        INSERT INTO EmployeeDetails (Name,
                                     City,
                                     Age)
        SELECT Name,
               City,
               Age
        FROM @ItemValues; -- Here i am Select Records from User_Define_Table_Type
        COMMIT TRANSACTION;
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        IF (@@Trancount > 0)
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
    END CATCH;
--select 1
END;
```

Type:

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[typList] AS TABLE(
    [Name] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [City] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Age] [varchar](100) NULL
)
```

Below is my query which I have fired manually to check the working of stored procedure and type which is working fine.

```
DECLARE @typList  AS typList
 
INSERT INTO @typList VALUES ( 'ABC', 'Mumbai','24')
INSERT INTO @typList VALUES ( 'DEF', 'Nasik','30')
INSERT INTO @typList VALUES ( 'GHI', 'Aurnagabad','28')

    
    
EXECUTE Usp_BulkInsert @typList
```

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Is there an error?

Comment: You can't perform bulk inserts this way. BULK INSERT is a *very* specific thing - rows are added in a stream using minimal logging. The server only logs entire data pages at a time, not individual rows. Your stored procedure performs fully logged INSERT instead. You can perform actual BULK INSERT operations using the SqlBulkCopy, as long as your data is in DataTable or IDataReader form. You can wrap any `IEnumerable` collection into an IDataReader using [FastMember's ObjectReader](https://github.com/mgravell/fast-member?tab=readme-ov-file#ever-needed-an-idatareader)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos at the TDS level, a TVP is *very similar* to BULK INSERT, so: I entirely support the description of this as "a bulk insert", meaning: an efficient insert of bulk data (compared to per-row `INSERT`), even if it doesn't use the BCP feature to avoid some logging overhead

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos btw and purely for your interest: Dapper.AOT has now inherited and superseded FastMember's implementation for this purpose

Comment: Is the real issue here using `.Query` instead of `.Execute` ? there is no `select` (or `output`) here (unless I'm overlooking it), so: this isn't a query; but @PanagiotisKanavos is correct that you could do this more efficiently using `SqlBulkCopy` and avoiding the `DataTable`, TVP and SP entirely - noting that `SqlBulkCopy` can support transactions, IIRC; if you tell us *what actually happens*, we can probably advise further

Comment: I pulled 3M rows from MySQL to SQL Server overnight using SqlBulkCopy. The logging overhead for this is significant and the rows are saved directly to the target. Using a TVP means the data is still temporarily saved to the server before performing an INSERT FROM.

Comment: hence my "but @PanagiotisKanavos  is correct that..." - it is certainly a significant step up from row-by-row `insert` ;p

Comment: As for Dapper.AOT - guess what I tried to do yesterday: use native AOT with  the data I pulled using Dapper and MySqlConnectorNet. 74MB for a tool that just passes an IDataReader to SqlBulkCopy is a bit too much

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos https://aot.dapperlib.dev/bulkcopy

Comment: Minor note: I actually *love* that this wasn't originally tagged [tag:dapper]; I'm hugely biased, but I'm choosing to interpret that as "well, naturally - we can take that as assumed!"

Comment: @DaleK No it doesn't give any error, I get success response but when I check database I cannot see any records.

Comment: @ShabluRizvi the stored procedure hides errors. The transaction itself is meaningless as `INSERT` is atomic. The only thing this `CATCH` does is hide errors

Answer (score 4):

> but it is not working

It is hard to be confident without more detail than "not working", but I can *reasonably speculate* that the problem here is as simple as using `.Query<T>(...)` when you should be using `.Execute(...)` - since this isn't a query.

Additionally, here:

```
var ItemValues = dataTable.AsTableValuedParameter("dbo.typList");
// ...
var output = con.Query<bool>("Usp_BulkInsert", ItemValues, ...
```

that's *not how parameters work with Dapper*, since the SP could take *multiple* parameters: you need to name them via members. The easiest way to do this would be:

```cs
var output = con.Query<bool>("Usp_BulkInsert", new { ItemValues }, ...
```

the `new {...}` here creates an anonymous type with one member *named* `ItemValues`, with the *value* from `ItemValues`, which is what we want.

Comment: "not working" in the sense it is not giving me any error it is giving success response but when I check database I can't find records there.

Comment: @ShabluRizvi I see you have a `try` .... is there also a `catch`? and if so: does that `catch` get reached? and if so: what is the actual exception being caught? Because if an exception is being swallowed: sure, that could be a side-effect

Comment: yes i do have catch but no exception is getting throws. I got frustrated.

Comment: @ShabluRizvi I genuinely don't believe that no exception is thrown, because the code *as shown* **does not have a query**, so  `.Query<T>` is going to have a very bad day; but: what is `output` after this operation? also: I've just noticed that the parameters is very wrong - see incoming edit (now edited)

Comment: @MarcGravell the stored procedure has a `CATCH` that rolls back and hides errors. INSERT is atomic so the only thing this does is hide any errors that prevented INSERT from working

Comment: @MarcGravell PS: no AOT for ExecuteReaderAsync ? (Sad Monkey face)

Comment: Log it and I'll prioritize it. I'm busy all this weekend (I'm "tech crew" for a theatre group , and we have performances all weekend), but I can look on Monday. That should be about half an hour's hack, I reckon. I just don't have that half an hour until then.

Answer (score 0):

You have a number of issues going on here:

- You need to put the parameter into another object (or a `DynamicParameters`).
- You need to use `.Execute` not `.Query`

```cs
using var con = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString());
con.Execute("Usp_BulkInsert", new { ItemValues }, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure, commandTimeout: 1000);
```

- You are swallowing errors with your `BEGIN CATCH`. **Do not** use a server-side `CATCH` unless you have special logging or handling involved (and then re-throw using `THROW;`). Otherwise just put `SET XACT_ABORT ON;` at the top of the procedure.
- Better yet: you don't need an explicit transaction anyway, because there is only one statement.

```sql
CREATE PROC [dbo].[Usp_BulkInsert] @ItemValues typList READONLY
AS

SET XACT_ABORT, NOCOUNT ON;

INSERT INTO dbo.EmployeeDetails
  (Name, City, Age)
SELECT
  Name,
  City,
  Age
FROM @ItemValues;
```

- As mentioned by others, you should probably just use `SqlBulkCopy`.

```cs
using var con = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString());
using var bulk = new SqlBulkCopy(con);
bulk.DestinationTableName = "dbo.EmployeeDetails";
foreach (var column in dataTable.Columns)
{
    bulk.ColumnMappings.Add(column.ColumnName, column.ColumnName); // add other mappings if desired
}
con.Open();
bulk.WriteToServer();
```

- Consider using `async` methods where possible.